# Enforcing <strong> instead of <b> in HTMLEditorKit/JEditorPane

Tags: java, swing, htmleditorkit

I am trying to ensure that the JEditorPane with HTMLEditorKit uses <**strong**> tags instead of <**b**> tags. The code below loads a JFrame with an JEditorPane. Try selecting a part of the text and clicking the button to turn the selection bold. The System.out shows that the bolding is being caused by  tags.

How do I set it up so that it is XHTML compliant and uses  tags instead?

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JEditorPane;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.event.DocumentEvent;
import javax.swing.event.DocumentListener;
import javax.swing.text.StyledEditorKit;
import javax.swing.text.html.HTMLEditorKit;

public class BStrongTest extends JPanel {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        frame.add(new BStrongTest());
        frame.setSize(300, 200);

        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public BStrongTest() {
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        final JEditorPane pane = new JEditorPane();
        pane.setEditorKit(new HTMLEditorKit());
        pane.setText("Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Praesent bibendum.");
        add(pane, BorderLayout.NORTH);

        JButton boldButton = new JButton();
        boldButton.setAction(new StyledEditorKit.BoldAction());
        boldButton.setText("Boldify");
        add(boldButton, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        pane.getDocument().addDocumentListener(new DocumentListener() {

            @Override
            public void changedUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
                System.out.println(pane.getText());
            }

            @Override
            public void insertUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
            }

            @Override
            public void removeUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: I'd imagine you'd have to implement/override one of the Java classes you are using such as `HTMLEditorKit` so that it used different tags. I've had a brief look through the source trying to trace back through `HTMLEditorKit` and it's going to take a while to identify the right class/methods to override. I don't have the time right now, sorry.

Comment: That's what I'm worried about. It seems like there should be a cleaner way, or an implementation by a 3rd party.

Comment: Please have a look at this [thread](http://www.java-forums.org/awt-swing/24048-jeditorpane-html-4-0-css-custom-tags.html), might be this can help :-) scroll to the middle, there is an answer, that I guess, might can help a bit :-) The post, it seems like tells how to add custom tags, though I really don't know, one can override the previously supplied thingy or not :(

Comment: That's an interesting read, but it doesn't force the standard Java implementation to work in a consistent manner.

Answer (score 1):

This answer is incomplete, I'm using it as a notepad when I keep coming back to continue.

`javax.swing.text.html.HTML` contains a class `Tag`, it also contains a large number of final `Tag` instances that represent each of the HTML tags.

We're interested in the line;

```
public static final Tag STRONG = new Tag("b");
```

`javax.swing.text.html.HTMLDocument` contains a `HashTable` `tagMap` that stores all of these tags.

We're interested in the lines;

```
tagMap.put(HTML.Tag.STRONG, ca);
```

Where `ca` is `TagAction ca = new CharacterAction();` and;

```
protected void registerTag(HTML.Tag t, TagAction a) {
    tagMap.put(t, a);
}
```

I've not located the package for `TagAction` yet or a way of accessing/changing the HTML document used by `HTMLEditorKit`.

---

I've located what I believe to be the point where a tag is written out (marked with the `//here`;

javax.swing.java.text.html.HTMLWriter.java

```
protected void writeEmbeddedTags(AttributeSet attr) throws IOException {

    // translate css attributes to html
    attr = convertToHTML(attr, oConvAttr);

    Enumeration names = attr.getAttributeNames();
    while (names.hasMoreElements()) {
        Object name = names.nextElement();
        if (name instanceof HTML.Tag) {
            HTML.Tag tag = (HTML.Tag)name;
            if (tag == HTML.Tag.FORM || tags.contains(tag)) {
                continue;
            }
            write('<');
            write(tag.toString());//Here
            Object o = attr.getAttribute(tag);
            if (o != null && o instanceof AttributeSet) {
                writeAttributes((AttributeSet)o);
            }
            write('>');
            tags.addElement(tag);
            tagValues.addElement(o);
        }
    }
}
```

So it looks asthough we need to change whatever builds the `attributeSet`s within the document being written.

Comment: +1, for bringing the search a bit near to its real goal. I hope though the arrow is going in the right direction :-)

Comment: I've also been looking in `HTMLWriter` as I presume that's what turns the `HTMLDocument` into a String, at a glance been unable to find in there where general tags like Strong are handled. So far I'd still say you'd be best off taking `HTML`, `HTMLDocument`, `HTMLEditorKit` and doing a ton of overloads.

Comment: I missed all your updates somehow. I fear you are correct and was hoping for another solution.

Comment: I forgot to add that I spent an hour or so looking through the source and couldn't spot any straight forwards method for replacing tags. You will probably have better luck looking for a library that provides the functionality you need.